# RStudio warning message: (from memory): as_tibble is changing .. please use

Tags: r, tibble

I am a relative newbie, using Rstudio 1.1.463 with R v3.6.1 and have updated all my packages.

I am aware that both `tibble::as.tibble` and `dplyr::tbl_df` are both deprecated, so as directed, I have been using `tibble::as_tibble` to create my tibbles instead.

Yesterday while running a script I wrote a few months ago (and ran fine before I updated R and packages) I saw a warning message to the effect that **as_tibble** is changing soon and directing me to use something else.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to capture the message, have been unable to recreate it, and despite checking GitHub, rdrrio, nabble, google and here, I am unable to confirm whether as_tibble is changing...

Tibbles tend to be my goto type of dataframe that I use, so any signposting, (or re-assurance that this is another of RStudio's mildly over-sensitive warnings) would be appreciated,

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what the warning was, but maybe related to the changes to as_tibble listed [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/news/news.html) under 2.0.0 breaking changes. `as_tibble` isn't going away though.

Comment: What were you passing to `as_tibble`? What kind of conversion do you require?

Comment: Thanks  @IceCreamToucan - that would seem to suggest I did see something, and not to worry about it for now.   @MrFlick I was passing a 1472 x 27 data.frame to `as_tibble`.